# Installing pptx via pip for enthought canopy error

Tags: python, installation, pip, canopy, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble getting [pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/install.html) set up to work with enthought canopy (I'm using Windows 8).

During installation using pip the following exception occurs. Notice that Pillow is uninstalled before the exception occurs. This is the only thing I can think that has gone wrong.

```
 ...running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to python_pptx.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing python_pptx.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to python_pptx.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to python_pptx.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'python_pptx.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'python_pptx.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Copying python_pptx.egg-info to C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\python_pptx-0.5.6-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to 'c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\temp\pip-guwbzu-record\install-record.txt'
  Found existing installation: Pillow 1.7.6
    Uninstalling Pillow:
      Removing file or directory c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilconvert.py
      Removing file or directory c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pildriver.py
      Removing file or directory c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilfile.py
      Removing file or directory c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilfont.py
      Removing file or directory c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilprint.py
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow
  Rolling back uninstall of Pillow
  Replacing c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilconvert.py
  Replacing c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pildriver.py
  Replacing c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilfile.py
  Replacing c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilfont.py
  Replacing c:\users\dirkh_000\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pilprint.py
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\build...
        Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
        requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
        requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 671, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
        pycompile=self.pycompile,
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 209, in clobber
        shutil.copy2(srcfile, destfile)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
        copyfile(src, dst)
      File "C:\Users\dirkh_000\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\Users\\dirkh_000\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Lib\\site-packages\\PIL\\_imaging.pyd'
```

The full debug log is available upon request.
Typing `import pptx` in canopy currently yields: `ImportError: No module named _util`

I'm thinking it's just a matter of mismatched directories, but I'm not sure how exactly to check if that's the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem when Canopy ***is*** running, but not when Canopy is ***not*** running.

Presumed reason: You can't replace the `_imaging.pyd` file (which is a Windows .DLL) when it is in use.

So quit Canopy and try again.

What the consequences will be for other packages that use PIL, I have no idea.

Comment: Restarting Canopy didn't work. Running installation as admin didn't work. However, Running installation as admin and then restarting Canopy did work. ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @DirkHaupt Don't restart Canopy. QUIT Canopy, use pip to install and then start Canopy.